# How to make branches of wikipedia?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Is it possible to put wikipedia into a git repository?
Just as an example:
I'd like to compile a new kind of wikipedia which does not only contain for example mathematical proofs, but contains math exercises. Obviously this wouldn't be accepted online. Is there a way to make something like this possible?

Comment: See [Wikipedia mirrors and forks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Mirrors_and_forks)

Comment: Forking 3 million+ articles, including all the ones about trains and cats, just so you can get the maths articles, seems like overkill. Also you won't get the benefit of future revisions on a fork. Why not start a new Wikibook at Wikipedia's sister site, http://wikibooks.org? There might even be one there already!

Comment: @Inductiveload: For educational purposes (with math exercises) http://Wikiversity.org would also be an option

Comment: @x3oo: Not sure why you have the git tag? Wikipedia does not use git for its history control on articles

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions for writing at wikibooks or wikiversity, you might consider using the Mediawiki API to get what you want, maybe even combining from wikipedia and wikibooks/wikiversity. You can even write your mash-up purely in HTML5 using the JSONP output type (i.e., use the JSON format with a callback parameter). The API would allow you, for example, to get only those articles belonging to the "Category:Articles containing proofs" category and then use the same article names on pages (or subpages--user subpages if not book subpages ought to work) at Wikiversity to allow for easy joining.

The APIs are available at the same relative path:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php
2. http://en.wikiversity.org/w/api.php
3. http://en.wikibooks.org/w/api.php